# Cracks along drywall corner bead

Tags: drywall, repair, paint, crack

I have a hairline crack along a drywall corner bead next to a window. I feel like this sort of crack is probably pretty common? What causes it? How can I fix it? What steps during drywall repair / installation should be taken to prevent it?

The home is 30 years old in a pretty dry climate (Colorado).
[image]

Comment: Find a piece of wood trim that looks good with the other trim In the room and cover the crack

Answer (score 1):

This may minimize the line you see with minimal effort and repair. Use a high grade latex painters caulk, cut a fine opening at the tip and force the caulk to seal the crack. With a bucket of water and damp sponge handy, wipe all the excess caulk off the surface. Make sure the sponge is only damp, no dripping water or it will wash out the caulk that was just set in place. Squeeze the sponge as hard as you can to get it only damp, then wipe one time using one side, turn the sponge and wipe another time. If the wall is not yet cleaned of caulk, rinse and do the same until it is. Paint to match. With this simple fix you have nothing to loose.

I believe the crack is from perhaps movement from the wood taking on moisture at one time and shrinking back again. I see the windows are not original to the house, or at least from what I can see they look like vinyl replacements. The original windows may have allowed some leakage, hence the replacement, and that did what you see there, but since the replacement it has been resolved. Or... it could have gotten abused during the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to installation error, causing outward tension across the corner and leaving too little mud burying the bead.

The bead should *not* be forced into position recklessly, it should be installed with just enough push to ensure an adequate coat of mud covers the flange and there is no outward tension on the flange.

For critical applications you might see a fine plasterer using a jig to help properly position the bead while fastening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How should I got about repairing? Embed a strip of drywall tape along the crack, sand, match the texture, and paint?

Comment: So, it could also be caused by wall movement... I would carefully scrape the mud from the area and re-mud, sand, texture, paint. So yes, not easy and just as likely that your repair will be equally (or more) noticeable than the crack unless you are an expert at matching texture. really, your best bet might be to scrape the line, caulk and paint, minimizing the need for texture match. And see @Kris comment, it really is not a bad idea to cover it...